# Apex Managed Sharing as customer portal user if class has "with sharing" modifier

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing

`Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get()` on a custom Share object is returning null when the user is a CP user and the class has the **with sharing** modifier even though the custom object has an OWD of private. If you remove **with sharing** or invoke the transaction as a standard SF user, it works as expected. I have other methods in the class that need sharing rule enforcement.

```
static sObject shareRecordWithUser(Id recordId, String objectName, Id userId) {
Schema.SObjectType shareType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName + '__Share');
SObject share = shareType.newSObject();    //  <--- NullPointerException
share.put('ParentId', recordId);
share.put('UserOrGroupId', userId);
share.put('AccessLevel', 'Edit');
return share;
}
```

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the documentation for "share" objects:

> Customer Portal users can't access this object.

Therefore, you need to use one of the other methods:

1. You can do this in a trigger, which always operate "without sharing" by default (*preferred*).
2. You can have an inner class "without sharing," which will allow the DML to succeed.
3. You can have a separate class, such as a utility class, that houses the function.